# CPU run-time feature detection on iOS API

Tags: ios

I need to detect whether the arm/aarch64 cpus of iOS devices support the following features at run-time: `fp`, `asimd`, `pmull`, `aes`, `sha1`, `sha2`, `sha3`, `sha512`, `crc32`, `atomics`, `fphp`, `asimdhp`, `asimdrdm`, `lrcpc`, `asimddp`, and `sve`.

What's the API to query this information?

Comment: So a generic version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637888/how-to-determine-armv8-features-at-runtime-on-ios perhaps?

Comment: Yeah. The question you mentioned has no answer :/

Comment: Coming from macOS, I would expect using sysctl with `machdep.cpu` to be available. Try calling it.